# What is the difference between `HashSet<T>.IsSubsetOf()` and `HashSet<T>.IsProperSubsetOf()`

Tags: c#, .net

What is the difference between these two method calls?

- `HashSet<T>.IsSubsetOf()`
- `HashSet<T>.IsProperSubsetOf()`

Comment: A subset can include the original set, a proper subset cannot. So if your comparison set is A, B, C, D, then A B C D can be a subset, but not a proper subset.

Comment: [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) article for subsets is helpful here. It describes a subset and a proper subset.

Comment: @hvd Actually it's now quite clear to me. For some reason I never considered the naming actually refers to the mathematical terms. I read the documentation for the methods, but didn't saw instantly the difference.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321100(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If the current set is a proper subset of other, other must have at least one element that the current set does not have.

vs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412074(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If other contains the same elements as the current set, the current set is still considered a subset of other.

The difference is `set.IsSubsetOf(set) == true`, whereas `set.IsProperSubsetOf(set) == false`

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the right paragraphs in the documentation. I read the descriptions for both methods, but somehow didn't came to this simple conclusion.

Answer (score 13):

This comes from the set theory:

```
S = {e,s,t}, T = {e,s,t}
```

T is a subset of S because every element in T is also in S. However it is not a proper subset, because a proper subset, like a normal subset too, contains elements of the superset, but it also has **less** elements than the initial collection. Example:

```
S = {e,s,t}, T = {e,t}
```

T is a proper subset of S.

Answer (score 4):

IsProperSubsetOf cannot contain the whole HashSet.  Only a part of it.
IsSubsetOf can contain any subset, including the full HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

From the "Examples" section [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358446%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The following example creates two disparate HashSet objects and
> compares them to each other. In this example, lowNumbers is both a
> subset and a proper subset of allNumbers until allNumbers is modified,
> using the IntersectWith method, to contain only values that are
> present in both sets. Once allNumbers and lowNumbers are identical,
> lowNumbers is still a subset of allNumbers but is no longer a proper
> subset.